# Android - Kotlin - Dagger 2 - Qualifier Annotation with Member Injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to inject a String into my class that is **qualified** by an annotation like this:

```
@Qualifier
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ChannelId
```

When working with constructor injection, everything is working well. Now, as I am implementing a Service, I need to lazily **inject** my `ChannelId`:

```
@Inject
@ChannelId
lateinit var channelId: String
```

My **Provider** looks like this:

```
@Provides
@ChannelId
fun channelId(): String = "channelid"
```

The compiler tells me, that I need to implement a `@Provides`-method for my String, although it is in my Object-Graph. 
I tested this with using `@Named` in the provider and Service:

```
@Inject
@field:Named("channelId")
lateinit var channelId: String
```

Dagger can now resolve the String and correctly inject it into my Service. Obviously I am missing something about the Qualifier-Annotation. Can anyone please help out?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it with `@field:ChannelId` as you did with `Named`?

Comment: It worked, thank you. I havent found anything yet that gave me this advice :) In case you give your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it worked. Someone just answered basically the same question, so I closed it instead :)

Comment: I don't think the questions are equal, as the other is related to named annotations and mine is related to qualifier annotations. I guess this is worth mentioning on this platform :)